# Switch from Cells to Range

Tags: excel, vba

I see [Range.AutoFill method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) example:

```
Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2") 
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20") 
sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

I want to input a formula into the first empty column (always row 2) and then copy that down for all rows in the register (it's data copied from an outside source).

```
Sub SetNextEmptyFormula(strFormula As Variant)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

  Set ws = Workbooks("myworkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("register")

  ' Always row 2 -> lRow, always in lCol
  lCol = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  lRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
  ws.Cells(2, lCol + i).Value = CStr(strFormula)

  Set sourceRange = ws.Range(???)
  Set fillRange = ws.Range(???)
  sourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, lCol + i),ws.cells(lRow,lCol + i)).Value= CStr(strFormula)`  But i is not declared or assigned a value so it is `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're going to build your formula, but if you're just looking for help referencing these cells, this will do:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UseSub()
    
    Dim myFormula
    myFormula = "=ROW()"
    Call SetNextEmptyFormula(myFormula)
    
End Sub
Sub SetNextEmptyFormula(strFormula As Variant)

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim fillRange As Range

    Set WS = Workbooks("myworkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("register")
   'Set WS = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("register")
    
    With WS
        
        ' Always row 2 -> lRow, always in lCol
        lCol = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        lRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        .Cells(2, lCol + 1).Formula = CStr(strFormula)
        
        'FillDown Only requires you reference the whole range Once, You only need "FillRange"
        'Set sourceRange = ws.Range(???)
        Set fillRange = .Range(.Cells(2, lCol + 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol + 1))
        fillRange.FillDown
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to put `ws.` in front of the `Cells` inside the range, or if that sheet is not the active one it will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks! Changed. Look right?